# How to use multiple views with single controler in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to use multiple views with single controller.
my problem is every view when call then controller run every time, but i want to do only function related to view is called.

Comment: Provide your code for :"every view when call then controller run every time".. It will be easy to help in right direction..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register views with the same name of controller

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.

```
    when("/Home", {
        templateUrl: "Pages/Home.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    }).
     when("/Login", {
         templateUrl: "Pages/Login.html",
         controller: "HomeController"
     }).

    otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/Home"
    });
```

});

Comment: in this case, every time on every view my controller is compiled. may cause performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can have many blocks in a view file like:

books.html

```
<div>
   <div ng-if="step=='add-books'">
       ------ view 1 -- Add Books
    </div>

    <div ng-if="step=='list-books'">
       ------ view 1 -- List of Books
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your controller change the value of $scope.step variable according to button clicks.

Comment: No, Sorry. i already use multiple views. but i want to manage only single controller with all views. And want to only perticular function run for single view not all function or code  compile every time.

Comment: Controller would be only one and you have to manage that $scope.step variable. Controller code will run only once.